# Isometric imbedding of a 2-disk into Euclidean 3-space

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

Let us call a *cap* the intersection of the boundary of 3-dimensional convex compact set $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with a half-space bounded by a plane $H$ such that the orthogonal projection to $H$ of this intersection is contained in $K\cap H$.

**QUESTION.** Given a metric on a closed 2-dimensional disk which has non-negative curvature in the sense of Alexandrov. Can the disk be isometrically imbedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a cap?

A reference would be helpful.

Comment: If you replace the convex cap with a *polyhedral cap*, and replace the given metric by a *polyhedral metric*, then I believe Alexandrov's results in *Convex Polyhedra* answers *Yes*. Perhaps your result can be obtained as a limit of polyhedral caps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take doubling of the disc, we obtain a metric on the sphere.
By Perelman's theorem it had nonnegative curvature in the sense of Alexandrov.
Therefore, by Alexandrov's theorem, it is isometric to a convex surface in the Euclidean space.
This convex surface is unique up to congruence (Pogorelov's theorem). Therefore, the involution of our sphere extends to a reflection of the space.
In particular, the boundary of the disc lies in one plane.

**Postscript.** You may also proceed as suggested by Joseph O'Rourke --- approximate the disc by polyhedral space, apply Alexandrov's theorem for polyhedral surfaces (which has uniqueness for free) and pass to the limit.

Comment: Yes, concerning "uniqueness for free," Alexandrov's Thm.3 p.184 says: *Isometric polyhedral caps are congruent*.

Comment: First, you probably misspelled Perelman. Second, what theorem of Perelman do you refer to?

Comment: If you have a metric of positive curvature on the (open) disk, and double it, in general you do not get a metric of positive curvature on the sphere. Some condition on the metric on the boundary is required (which is absent in the question).

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko nonnegative curvature in the sense of Alexandrov implies convexity of the boundary.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko (sorry did not noticed that you have two comments) yes, I will fix the spelling, it is the so-called doubling theorem --- it says that doubling of Alexandrov space across its boundary is an Alexandrov space.

Comment: @Anton Petrunin: and this doubling them is due to Perelman? Can you give a reference?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko see p.28 here: https://anton-petrunin.github.io/papers/alexandrov/perelmanASWCBFB2+.pdf